# Symfony2 / Elastica-bundle

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I've just install a symfony2 project with elastica bundle, elasticsearch is running.
I've configured the fos_elastica so that my entity (example car) will be automaticly reindex in elasticsearch. 
Everything work fine.

Here is how it work:

in my controller

```
$em->flush();
```

then when the entity is persisted in the database, it calls

```
$this->dispatchPostFlushEvent();
```

and now in the ContainerAwareEventManager.php, i can find the method dispatch event which will raise an event to reindex the entity in elastic search (in dispatchEvent() )

What i expect to do is raise this event manually instead of automaticly

I mean this kind of usage:

```
$em->flush();
$em->flushAndReindexEs();
```

Or

```
$em->flush()
$this->raiseEvent('reindex-elastic-entity', $em, array('title' => 'string')
```

Does somebody see an easy way to do such thing ?

I pursue with investigating the dispatchEvent.

Any help will be helpful ;)
Thx

Answer (score 2):

`FOSElasticaBundle` implements event listener that sends updates on `postFlush` event.

So you need to implement your own event listener that will collect informations about scheduled (for persisting, updating or removal) entities (you could take a look at `FOS\ElasticaBundle\Doctrine\Listener` as an example) and also event listener that will catch your own event that you will fire manually -- and sends updates to ES (via `FOS\ElasticaBundle\Persister\ObjectPersister`).

And also you could take a look at [this example](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/67nu/creating-a-custom-listener-in-symfony-to-manually-update-elasticsearch-index-for-parent-object).